# How to convert a country code to the corresponding currency?

Tags: java, currency, country-codes

I need to convert a country code to a currency in my app on a user basis.

Based on my geolocation library, I know whether the user is in the United States (US), Germany (DE), Switzerland (CH), Japan (JPY), etc. Now I need to convert from the country code to the corresponding currency:

```
US -> USD ($)
DE -> EURO (€)
CH -> CHF (CHF)
JP -> YEN (JPY)
```

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Maybe worth checking out [Java Locales](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/locale/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies) and store it in your database.

It's hard to build good databases suited to an apps need from Internet sources, but it's really worth it. To parse html, I suggest you try regexp, and if it gets too complicated, please use [apache jericho](http://jerichohtml.sourceforge.net/) or [tag soup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The standard JDK supports major foreign currencies:

```
System.out.println(DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(12.34));
System.out.println(DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(12.34));
```

Outputs:

```
$12.34
12,34 €
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Do you know of any wider ones?  That one only supports very few currencies

Comment: @Adam which currency in particular do you want to support?

Comment: Rand from South Africa

Comment: @adam `DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("en_ZA")).format(12.34));`

Answer (score 0):

What about this? It's a hack but seems to work okay.

```
/**
 * 
 */
package lt;

import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * LocaleTest - LocaleTest
 * @version 1.0
 * @author <a href="mailto:Dessimat0r@ntlworld.com">Chris Dennett</a>
 */
public class LocaleTest {
    public static final Map<String, Currency> CURRENCIES = new HashMap<String, Currency>();
    static {
        for (Locale l : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
            try {
                Currency c = Currency.getInstance(l);

                if (c != null) {
                    CURRENCIES.put(l.getCountry(), c);
                    System.out.println("key: " + l.getCountry() + ", loc: " + l + ", curr: " + c + " (" + c.getSymbol(l) + ")");                
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    public static final void main(String args[]) {
        if (args == null || args.length == 0 || (args[0] = args[0].trim()).isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Please provide an argument!");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("LocaleTest: got " + args[0] + " as argument");
        Currency c = CURRENCIES.get(args[0]);
        if (c != null) {
            System.out.println("LocaleTest: got " + c + " (" + c.getSymbol() + ") as currency");
        } else {
            System.out.println("LocaleTest: no currency found for " + args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output with GB given:

```
...
key: YE, loc: ar_YE, curr: YER (?.?.?)
key: MK, loc: mk_MK, curr: MKD (Den)
key: CA, loc: en_CA, curr: CAD ($)
key: VN, loc: vi_VN, curr: VND (?)
key: NL, loc: nl_NL, curr: EUR (€)
key: US, loc: es_US, curr: USD (US$)
key: CN, loc: zh_CN, curr: CNY (?)
key: HN, loc: es_HN, curr: HNL (L)
key: US, loc: en_US, curr: USD ($)
..
LocaleTest: got GB as argument
LocaleTest: got GBP as currency
```

An issue is that a currency may display the name as symbol rather than the symbol ($ £ etc.). The currency has to be created with the locale of its originating country for that to work. If you fix this, you might still have currencies with symbols that don't look right.